# Error: el índice está fuera de los límites de la tabla

Tags: c#

Estoy seleccionando un combobox desde el codigo c# pero a veces me da el siguiente error:

el índice está fuera de los límites de la tabla.

Muestro el codigo que pienso que esta dando el problema:

```
int entityCount = e.Packet.ReadInteger();
            var entityList = new List<HEntity>(entityCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < entityList.Capacity; i++)
            {
                int id = e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                string name = e.Packet.ReadString();
                string motto = e.Packet.ReadString();
                string figureId = e.Packet.ReadString();
                int index = e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                int x = e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                int y = e.Packet.ReadInteger();

                var z = double.Parse(
                    e.Packet.ReadString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                int type = e.Packet.ReadInteger();

                HGender gender = HGender.Unisex;
                string favoriteGroup = string.Empty;
                #region Switch: type
                switch (type)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            gender = SKore.ToGender(e.Packet.ReadString());
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            favoriteGroup = e.Packet.ReadString();
                            e.Packet.ReadString();
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();

                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadString();
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();
                            e.Packet.ReadBoolean();
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadString();
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        {
                            e.Packet.ReadString();
                            e.Packet.ReadInteger();
                            e.Packet.ReadString();

                            for (int j = e.Packet.ReadInteger(); j > 0; j--)
                                e.Packet.ReadShort();

                            break;
                        }
                }
                #endregion

                var entity = new HEntity(id, index, name,
                    new HPoint(x, y, z), motto, gender, figureId, favoriteGroup);

                entityList.Add(entity);
            }

            foreach (HEntity Player in entityList)
            {
                playerList.Items.Add(Player.Index + "`" + Player.Name + "`" + Player.FigureId + "`" + Player.Gender + "`" + Player.Motto);

            }
```

Por otra parte selecciono el combobox de la siguiente manera:

```
int fu = e.Packet.ReadInteger();
        string nam = e.Packet.ReadString();
        foreach (var item in playerList.Items)
        {

            string pe = item.ToString();
            string[] re = pe.Split('`');
            int UserInd = int.Parse(re[0]);
            string User = re[1];
            if (User == nam)
            {
                var count = playerList.Items.Count;
                if (count>1)
                playerList.SelectedItem = item;
                else
                    playerList.SelectedItem = false;
            }
```

Comment: ¿Qué valores posee el ComboBox? Para conocer dónde puede estar el problema, encierre su código fuente en un bloque try/catch [ejemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4272579/4092887). Actualice su pregunta con esta información.

Comment: en que contexto o evento estas ubicando este codigo ? porque tienes que realizar un for de la entityList si despues agregas un item con Add() ?

Comment: estoy utilizando triggers por lo que por una parte selecciono la lista con el codigo de abajo y con otra agrego los elementos nada mas un salu2

Comment: Indique el codigo donde da el fallo es el primero

Answer (score 2):

No puedes recorrer en un `for` la lista `entityList` y al mismo tiempo realizar un `Add()`.

La lista podrías recorrerla de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach (var entiry in entityList)
{
   //aquí código

   entity = new HEntity(id, index, name,
                new HPoint(x, y, z), motto, gender, figureId, favoriteGroup);
}
```

La idea es que si iteras la lista después la instancia la asignas sobre ese ítem que ya habías creado y no usar el `Add()` que crearía uno nuevo.